# Add two sliding track on one sliding rail in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slider

[image]

I am using a material-ui slider component.

What I am trying to achieve is to have two sets of sliders which do not overlap so the user can select two intervals.

Best methods I can think of for now

1. To put a div of the color same as unselected rail and place it
   between 40 and 70 and whenever slider's value changes dynamically
   increase length of that div so to cover the length between point 2
   and point 3 on the slider which looks like there is no track between
   40 and 70
2. Just have two points (one set of sliding track) allow user to select
   the interval and then store it and ask him to select again while restricting
   them to select any part of the previous interval

I have two things that I want to know:

Is there a better way to make user select two intervals which do not overlap.

Is there a way I can remove  track between 40 and 70

link to [material ui sliders](https://material-ui.com/components/slider/)